# Getting data from a method in another class

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am pretty much confused.

I am trying to make an program where I want to keep my .cs file with layout clean and not messy.

So I made a seperate .cs file for all of the background work, such as fetching data from the internet.

My viewcontroller is called "test_spaceViewController.cs" and the file where I want my class with all methods is called "test_functions.cs".

It runs just fine and my console outputs "Data loaded" as it should, however I aint got a clue on how to fetch the string "hi".

My "test_functions.cs" does look like this:

```
using System;

namespace test_space
{
    public class functions
    {

        public void getData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Data loaded");


            string hi;

            hi = "Hello";

        }
    }
}
```

And my "test_spaceViewController.cs"

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace test_space
{
    public partial class test_spaceViewController : UIViewController
    {

        public test_spaceViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        #region View lifecycle

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();


            functions functions = new functions ();
            functions.getData ();


        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to approach this, but the simplest is to simply return the data from your getData() function.

```
public string getData()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Data loaded");

    string hi;

    hi = "Hello";

    return hi;
}
```

Then in your controller,

```
string mydata = functions.getData ();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to add the string variable to a Console.WriteLine and it should display

Console.WriteLine ("Data loaded" + hi );

or create a another Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine (hi);
Console.WriteLine ("Data loaded");
this should display

Hello
Data Loaded
```